# How can I use (select * from table_name) instead of (the list) in a TYPE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create type number_table is table of number;

FOR r IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS site
               FROM TABLE (number_table (55578622,
                                         70422825,
                                         71659843,
                                         77226904,
                                         78231463,
                                         80292748,
                                         81090361,
                                         81519938,
                                         81914339,
                                         82318250,
                                         85413629,
                                         85869431,
                                         86549326,
                                         86563882)
```

How can I use (select * from table_name) instead of (the list) ??

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem when you use like a `list`.

Alternative could be :

> How can I use (select * from table_name) instead of (the list) ??

```
SELECT CURSOR (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS site
                 FROM TABLE (number_table (55578622,
                                      70422825,
                                      71659843,
                                      77226904,
                                      78231463,
                                      80292748,
                                      81090361,
                                      81519938,
                                      81914339,
                                      82318250,
                                      85413629,
                                      85869431,
                                      86549326,
                                      86563882))) col
  FROM DUAL  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty automatic with Implicit cursor ([see more](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_implicit_cursor_FOR_loop.htm)): What about like this?

```
--- say table_name as 3 cols: c1, c2, c3
FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM table_name) 
LOOP
  -- do something with r
  dbms_output.put_line('c1 is:'||r.c1);
  dbms_output.put_line('c2 is:'||r.c2)
  dbms_output.put_line('c3 is:'||r.c3)

END LOOP;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: OP wanted to use it in a `SELECT` statement not a `BLOCK`

Comment: @XING, I agree I might not have entirely understand OP... It could be anything, couldn't it?

Comment: Question is pretty clear. I dont find any issue  understanding it. Not sure if you found so.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked... I'm completely overthinking!

Comment: @J.Chomel I only reply according to what asked. I just read through the question and reply accordingly. I dont like guessing. Also not sure from which answer OP is satisfied as i can see he replied to our conversation.

Comment: @C.Anderton, if this worked for you, this is good news. Then you might be interested in this topic here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)